# Errors While Installing laptop-mode-tools

Tags: laptop

I'm receiving the following errors when trying to install laptop-mode-tools.

Xubuntu 14.10.  Kernel 3.16.0-25-generic.

```
Setting up laptop-mode-tools (1.64-1ubuntu1) ...
sh: echo: I/O error
sh: echo: I/O error
Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
Failed.
 * Laptop mode 
enabled, active
SETTING OF KERNEL PARAMETER FAILED: echo ondemand \> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
SETTING OF KERNEL PARAMETER FAILED: echo ondemand \> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

How can I fix this and get the most out of laptop-mode-tools?